# What is the type of a lambda expression for the compiler?

Tags: c++, lambda, gdb

So, if we run the `gdb` on the following source code :

```
//...
auto myLambda1 = [&](int x){ printf("Hi, I got x=%d here\n",x);};
auto myLambda2 = [&](double y){ printf("Hi, I got y=%f here\n",y);};
//...
```

I will get :

```
(gdb) ptype myLambda1
type = struct <lambda(int)> {
}
(gdb) ptype myLambda2
type = struct <lambda(double)> {
}
```

So what is a lambda expression for a compiler? Why it's a `struct`

Comment: Check [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/5d4bd092) for examples how the compiler may create unique `class`es/`struct`s for your lambdas

Comment: As a general observation, try to ditch the habit of using auto-capture-by-reference.  In this case, there's zero need for captures.  In more general cases, capturing everything by reference can lead to accidents that are very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a lambda expression is a class type, but it has no name. The most important feature of the class is that it has a public `operator()` so that it can be used in a function-call expression syntax.

Tons of technical details are in the Standard section [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure), which begins with

> The type of a *lambda-expression* (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the *closure type*, whose properties are described below.